# Keeping typings.json typing versions in-sync with bower.json

Tags: typescript, gulp, bower, typescript-typings

I'm trying to find a way to keep the .d.ts files referenced in typings.json in-sync with dependencies defined in bower.json. I'd like my Gulp build process to check bower to see what version of an external library I'm using and attempt to download the correct .d.ts file.

The only information I've been able to find on this is a Gulp plugin [bower-typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-typings) which was last updated in August 2015. and doesn't seem to be very popular.

How do TypeScript developers keep their .d.ts file versions in-sync with Bower dependencies? Is it a manual process to ensure that bower.json and typings.json match?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it is a manual process.
@types in TS2.0 may better solve that problem for npm (in the future), but even that doesn't solve the problem with bower

Comment: You can write a script to read those two files and do some sync yourself thou. No one would stop you from doing that. :)  Also, it would be even better if you release a tool for it. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the interested: after more research I decided to not spend much time on Typings and instead move towards using npm for both dependencies and typings. I don't have that approach fully figured out but it seems to be more in line with where TypeScript is heading.